# Mongoose nested schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to make a system of topics. each topic may have subtopics which are also topics.
meaning the subtopics may also have subtopics.
for example
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzcWP.png)

I tried to create a topic schema and add a subtopic field which will ref to topic schema too. 
cant seem to get this working my schema code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TopicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String,unique:true},
    sub_topic:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Topic'}] 
});

const Topic =mongoose.model('Topic', TopicSchema);
module.exports = Topic;
```

Also what the data im sending to the server should look like to make a new instance?
and on the server how do i save it?

i try to  save like this now :
const topic = new Topic();

```
topic.name = req.body.name;
topic.sub_topic.name=req.body.sub_topic
```

and the data im sending is :(json)

```
{
    "name":"TestMain",
    "sub_topic":[{"name":"TestSub"}]            
}
```

> UPDATE : got this done using a recursive function.

```
function subtopicHandler(topic, sub_topic) {
    Topic.find({
      "name": topic.name
    }, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err
      return;
    })

    if (sub_topic == undefined) {
      let ntopic = new Topic();
      ntopic.name = topic.name;
      ntopic.sub_topic == undefined;
      ntopic.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) console.log('saving err', err)
      });
      return ntopic._id;
    }
    let mainTopic = new Topic();
    mainTopic.name = topic.name;
    sub_topic.forEach(function (sub) {
      mainTopic.sub_topic.push(subtopicHandler(sub, sub.sub_topic));
    })
    var retME;
    mainTopic.save(function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('saving err', err)
        throw err;
      }
    });
    return mainTopic._id;

  }
```

Using this schema :

```
const TopicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String,unique:true},
    sub_topic:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Topic'}] 
});
```

and data sent as :

```
{
    "name":"A",
    "sub_topic":[
                    {"name":"C","sub_topic":
                        [
                            {"name":"C1"}
                            ,
                            {"name":"C2"}
                        ]
                    }
                    ,
                    {"name":"B"}
                    ,
                    {"name":"D","sub_topic":
                        [
                            {"name":"D1"}
                            ,
                            {"name":"D2"}
                            ,
                            {"name":"D3"}
                        ]
                    }
                ]            
}
```

to the API endpoint
handled this way:

```
let mainTopic = new Topic();
    mainTopic.name = req.body.name;
    subtopicHandler(mainTopic, req.body.sub_topic);
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending following json

```
const obj = {
    "name":"TestMain",
    "sub_topic":[{"name":"TestSub"}]            
}
```

Then,

```
let mainTopic = new Topic();
let subTopic = new Topic();

// assuming for now you have only one sub-topic in array
subTopic.name = obj[0].name;

subTopinc.save(function(err,result)=>{
    if(!err){
        mainTopic.name = obj.name;
        mainTopic.sub_topic = [result._id]
        mainTopic.save(function(err,result){
            console.log(result);
        })
    }
});
```

From you schema definition and the given json you can follow the above step to get the results.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, what if i wanted to have unlimited subtopics meaning the client can send over somthing with the subtopic has more subtopics. i want to make somthing like in folder system so Folder>subfolder>subfolder...and each subfolder can have subfolders. like a tree

Comment: Yes that's possible with this approach.

Comment: For example, you have MaiTopic>SubTopic>SuperSubTopic>NSuperSubTopic. Here NSuperSubTopic have SuperSubTopic as its MainTopic so you will save NSuperSubTopic first and you will pass that id in array of SuperSubTopic. Hope you getting me same way SubTopic is MainTopic of SuperSubTopic and so on...

Comment: thank you. ended up doing this with a recursive function to link them up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sub docs check out the documentation.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i tried figuring it out from the docs prior to asking :) didnt find a way to nest a schema in itself to create some sort of like Folder>subfolder>subfolder> and so on...